# Command line html formatter that works on linux (or a way to do this in PHP)?

Tags: php, html

Does anyone know of a linux-compatible command line html formatter? You know, something where I could pass it a file that looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
hi
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And it gives me:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>
            hi
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using PHP to generate this html, so if there is some handy way to do this via php that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/). It cleans and formats XML and HTML. There is also a PHP extension, but you would probably need to buffer your output and pass it through there.

**Edit:**
A code example:

```
ob_start();
// output your html
$output = ob_get_flush();

// Specify configuration
$config = array(
           'indent'         => true,
           'output-xhtml'   => true,
           'wrap'           => 200);

// Tidy
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();

// Output
echo $tidy;
```

I didn't test this, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed Tidy, but I didn't notice it had an indent option.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at PHP's [Tidy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php) offering.